# Gin BindJSON как получить все ошибки в JSON?

Tags: golang, golang-gin

Есть моделька:

```golang
type User struct {
   gorm.Model
   name          string `json:"name, db:name"`
   ShopID        uint   `json:"shop_id,  db:shop_id"`
   GroupID       uint   `json:"group_id, db:group_id"`
}
```

Если попытаться забиндить ей *JSON* со строковыми `ShopID` и `GroupID`, будет ошибка, что логично, так как тип не совпадает:

```golang
err = c.BindJSON(&user)
```

```json
{
   "name": "Foo",
   "shop_id": "1"
   "group_id": "1"
}
```

В `err` лежит ошибка только для первого поля, как получить все ошибки в *JSON* списком, чтобы отдавать их фронту не по одной?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде не одна ошибка, а все три. Во-первых, у вас неправильное
использование меток полей структуры. Должно быть:

```golang
type User struct {
   gorm.Model
   name    string `json:"name" db:"name"`
   ShopID  uint   `json:"shop_id" db:"shop_id"`
   GroupID uint   `json:"group_id" db:"group_id"`
}
```

Во-вторых, у вас поле `name` не экспортировано. Должно быть:

```golang
type User struct {
   gorm.Model
   Name    string `json:"name" db:"name"`
   ShopID  uint   `json:"shop_id" db:"shop_id"`
   GroupID uint   `json:"group_id" db:"group_id"`
}
```

В-третьих, если у вас в *JSON* строки, а в *Go* вам нужны
числа, то надо использовать атрибут `,string`:

```golang
type User struct {
   gorm.Model
   Name    string `json:"name" db:"name"`
   ShopID  uint   `json:"shop_id,string" db:"shop_id"`
   GroupID uint   `json:"group_id,string" db:"group_id"`
}
```

Что же касается вашего вопроса напрямую, насколько мне известно,
возвращается первая встреченная ошибка. Можете брать
[`json.(*Decoder).Token`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token)
и разбирать токены самостоятельно.

---

<sup>Зачем вам вообще `gin` и `gorm`? Читайте
стандартную библиотеку, там почти всё есть.</sup>